# Pascal's law - Glass Flask Experiment (doubt)

Tags: pressure, fluid-statics

[image: *This image was of my book.*]

This image was of my book and written below this image was that when the piston is pushed down, it is observed that liquid flow out with equal pressure from each hole. But, I think that pressure at the lowermost hole should be the most as pressure increases with depth and the lowermost hole is at the greatest depth. Am I wrong? If yes,then please explain me the reason.

Answer (score 1):

Ur question is right but in a flask the effect of gravity is negligible so the pressure on all points will remain same.
Ur point could be considered while dealing with large volumes under gravity.
I feel it might be helpful.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Physics SE. I think this  is a tip, rather than an answer, so you should post it as a comment. Please,  try to use a more formal language too.